# Changing of the UIButton name on runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have three UIButtons named tabItem2,tabItem3 and tabItem4. The tags of the tabItems and text of the labels are dynamic and depend on the value of the items in the InfoDictionary. I have created the switch to based on the tags and these tags applies to all three buttons. How do I change the code below, to suit the different buttons? I need the button names to be changeable-> meaning to say the switch statements should work for all three buttons.

The code looks like this:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *tabItem4;
    IBOutlet UIButton *tabItem2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *tabItem3;

IBOutlet UILabel *tabItem4Label;
    IBOutlet UILabel *tabItem2Label;
    IBOutlet UILabel *tabItem3Label;

NSArray *tabItemArray = [self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:@"tabitem"];
    for(int i = 0; i <[tabItemArray count]; i++)
     {
         NSString *nameOfTab = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tabItem%d",i+2];
         NSLog(@"%@",nameOfTab);
         switch ([[tabItemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]) {
             case kTabGameButtonTag:
                 nameOfTab.tag = kTabGameButtonTag;
                 nameOfTabLabel.text = kTabTitleTextGame;
                 [nameOfTab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"game.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             case kTabVideoButtonTag:
                 nameOfTab.tag = kTabVideoButtonTag;
                 nameOfTabLabel.text = kTabTitleTextVideoClip;
                 [nameOfTab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             case kTabQuizButtonTag:
                 nameOfTab.tag = kTabVideoButtonTag;
                 nameOfTabLabel.text = kTabTitleTextQuiz;
                 [nameOfTab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }
```

Need some guidance on this.

EDIT:

```
$1 = 0x0a219f50 {
tabitem =     (
        2000,
        2001,
        2002
    );
}
```

The rest of the items in the dictionary are confidential. So i have shared only the important information.

Comment: Can you share the details of InfoDictionary

Comment: If the tabButton's are declared as properties can you try accessing and assigning buttons using self.tabItem2,self.tabItem3, self.tabItem4 etc.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Does it not work? Do you want 'cleaner code'?

Comment: I am doing these things in viewdidload..

Comment: switch statement should work for all three buttons.

Comment: I don't see any buttons in your code. You've defined `nameOfTab` as an `NSString`, it doesn't make sense to set `tag`, `text`, and `image` properties for that...

Comment: i need to change it accordingly. how do i do it? that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking through, I solved the question this way:

```
 NSArray *tabItemArray = [self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:@"tabitem"];
    NSMutableArray *tabItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem2,tabItem2Label,tabItem3,tabItem3Label,tabItem4,tabItem4Label,nil];
    for(int i = 0,j = 0 ; i <[tabItemArray count]; i++, j=j+2)
     {
         UIButton  *item1 =  [tabItems objectAtIndex:j];
         UILabel  *label1 = [tabItems objectAtIndex:j+1];
         switch ([[tabItemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]) {
             case kTabGameButtonTag:
                 item1.tag = kTabGameButtonTag;
                 label1.text = kTabTitleTextGame;
                 [item1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"game.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             case kTabVideoButtonTag:
                 item1.tag = kTabVideoButtonTag;
                 label1.text = kTabTitleTextVideoClip;
                 [item1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             case kTabQuizButtonTag:
                 item1.tag = kTabVideoButtonTag;
                 label1.text = kTabTitleTextQuiz;
                 [item1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were setting image instead of backgroundImage of button try this code. I don't think another label is needed to display just the title of button

> ```
> [nameOfTab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"game.png"] 
>            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> ```

Replace with this

> ```
> [nameOfTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"game.png"] 
>                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> ```